# How can I disable the onPress function when user use the onLongPress function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a code looks like this

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor={colors.GRAYISHRED} onPress={() => alert('You tapped the button!')} onLongPress={() => alert('You tapped Longpress!') }>
    <List>
    <ListItem>
        <Text......</Text>
    </ListItem>
    </List>...
    ......
</TouchableHighlight>
```

My scenario is

when the user click is **onPress** it will go to next screen.

when the user click **onLongPress** it will pop up the check button to select each List.

is it possible when the user click onLongPress trigger the onPress will disable or not functioning temporarily, but if the user onLongPress again it will unable again the onPress function ?

Comment: My first thought is that I'd have the onLongPress function track isLongPress (true|false) and conditionally include the onPress function based on that.

Comment: I think the both functionality will work smoothly. No need to handle them onPress and onLongPress

Comment: ohh you mean that onLongPress track  (true|false)

if True - onpress will not next screen 
if False - onPress will go clickable as check :)